# What is to trip down the aisle?

Tags: phrase-meaning, figurative-language

Check the box office for great seats!                                               The smash hit musical based on the songs of ABBA
MAMMA MIA! A mother. A daughter. 3 possible dads. And a trip down the aisle you’ll never forget!

Comment: It's an "oblique" reference to walking down the aisle *in a church, **when getting married***. Calling that short walk a "trip" is just a slightly whimsical "flourish" (it's a short *linear distance*, but by the end of that "journey" the newlyweds are in a very different state than when they started! :)

Answer (score 2):

### It's a noun, not a verb.

Your question ("what is ***to trip down the aisle***?") indicates you think the word `trip` is being used as a verb.

"Trip" **can** be used as a verb <sup>([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/trip#cacd-2-1))</sup> .. but here it is a simple noun:

> Original:  A trip {down the aisle} you'll never forget!
>
> **Simplified**:  A trip you will never forget.
>
> **Simplified**:  You will never forget {this} trip {down the aisle}.

When you re-order the sentence, the word {this} is appropriate, because it's a noun.  Compare:

> ❌ *Incorrect*:  You will never forget {to} trip {down the aisle}.

As @FumbleFingers stated in the comments, "down the aisle" is used to suggest *walking down the aisle of a church, when getting married.*

> **Further simplified**:  A wedding you will never forget.
>
> Or:
>
> **Further simplified**:  You will never forget this wedding.

Comment: More importantly, *trip* here means *voyage* or *journey*, ***not*** *stumble*. It might be helpful to explicitly add the definition of the noun rather than relying on the external source.